# Formatting two lists into a single dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding a hangman game for my Computer Science class, and I'm trying to create a dictionary that has each character of the word given and a 0 to notate whether it's been guessed or not.

```
gamestart = 0
guesses = 5
gamewin = 0
while gamestart == 0:
    word = input("Welcome to hangman!" + "\nEnter a word: ")
    if word.find(" ") > -1:
       print("\nSorry Please use one word only!\n")
    elif word.find(" ") == -1:
        gamestart = 1
for i in range(len(word)):
    wordspacing = [0] * i
wordstore = list(word)
wordstore = dict(zip(wordspacing, wordstore))
print(wordstore)
```

however when I try to put the two lists I have together I get the output:

```
Welcome to hangman!
Enter a word: word
{0: 'r'}
```

Could someone identify the reason for this happening. I would also like a little bit of criticism in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are making a dictionary of `0` to letters, and each key can only have one value.

Try just using a dictionary comprehension

```
wordstore = {letter: 0 for letter in word}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired output using your method you need to switch the order of the zipped objects

```
wordstore = dict(zip(wordstore, wordspacing))
```

Also for wordspacing, you don't want to continually assign a value to `wordspacing`, plus you only end up with `[0,0,0]` instead of `[0,0,0,0]` since the last value of i is 3 and not 4. So go with the following

```
wordspacing = [0] * len(word)
```